# Google Maps V3 Directions Panel - a way to turn off step directions functionality?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

Basically I want to turn off the feature that centers the map on each turn when you click on Directions Panel step.

Is there a way to disable that feature?

PS: i tried:

```
suppressMarkers: true,
suppressInfoWindows: true,
```

but those only take out the markers and infowindows - it still centers the map on the turn point when its clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I ended up doing:

```
function getDirections()
{   
    var request = 
    {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_steps');

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
    {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
        {

            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);      

            var legs = response.routes[0].legs; 

            for (var leg = 0; leg < legs.length; leg++) {
                for (var step = 0; step < legs[leg].steps.length;
                step++) {
                    if (legs[leg].steps[step].lat_lngs) {                       
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += legs[leg].steps[step].instructions+"<br/><br/>";                                                      
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can render the DirectionsPanel yourself (rather than using the DirectionsRenderer).  That gives you complete control.

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html)

Comment: aarrgggg....i would have to rebuild the whole functionality of the directions panel just without that feature...argggggg...hmmm...is there no other option?

Answer (score 0):

Completely late, but for future references what worked for me was commenting these lines:

```
var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            draggable: true,
            map: map//,
            //panel: document.getElementById('right-panel') step directions instructions here
        });
```